# Reaching Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

So lets say I have a `Panel`. Inside of it there is a `Button` and `TextBox`. I can reach those controls' control with `panel.Controls[index]` with this way.

I am trying to reach `panel` with reverse way. I mean lets say I click the `textbox` inside of `panel`. And the active control of `form` became the `textbox`. Is there any possible way to reach that `panel` with active control?

`Panel -> Textbox` instead of `Active Control -> Panel`

Thanks

Comment: What UI tech are you using? WinForms, WPF, MAUI?

Comment: You can walk along `Control.Parent`, e.g. `textbox.Parent.Parent.Parent`. (though if `panel` is the immediate parent of `textbox` then just do `if( textbox.Parent is Panel panel ) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also i am using winform